# Handling large numbers of optional fields in redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux, redux-form

The app I'm working on has an array of suppliers, each containing an array of products. We're looking at about 20 suppliers, and 4k products total (across all suppliers) at the moment, although this could easily get much larger.

Our ordering view displays the list of suppliers on the side of the page, and clicking the supplier then renders a list of products for that supplier. Each item in the list contains an amount field for that specific product. Essentially the entire form requires 4k fields, one for each product.

My question is what is the best approach for controlling this large a number of fields when using `redux-form`?

The first solution might be to use redux-form's `<FieldArray />` and have a form structure like so:

```
{
  suppliers: [
    {
      id: 'supplier0',
      notes: 'Some notes for this supplier',
      products: [
        {
          id: 'product0',
          amount: 10
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However if I'm not mistaken this would require initialising the form with entries for all 4k products (since they're not being added or removed dynamically while the form is in use). It also means that any sort of processing on the form, like submitting, requires looping over all products to check if they have an amount value.

Alternatively I've been thinking I could maybe use an indexed structure like this:

```
{
  suppliers: {
    {{supplierId}}: {
      notes: 'Some notes for this supplier',
      products: {
        {{productId}}: {
          amount: 10
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then for each rendered row I just construct the amount field name using the supplier and product ids:

```
<Field name={`suppliers.${supplierId}.products.${productId}.amount`} />
```

This would save having to do any initialisation, and therefore keep the form state much more manageable.

I haven't really come across this anywhere else, and can't see any examples of such a use case in `redux-form`'s docs. Is there any downside to this second indexed approach? Any reason I absolutely should be using `FieldArray` instead?

Comment: Is it really necessary to make these fields controlled? Redux doesn't require each component to be controlled.

Comment: Users often order 100-200 products at once. Is there a feasible alternative to using controlled fields?

Comment: I'd suggest you to read these articles: [1](https://goshakkk.name/submit-time-validation-react/), [2](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/html5-form-validation-in-react-65712f778196). It may allow to implement complex forms without controlled inputs or, at least, without bulky libraries such as redux-form.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - thanks for these articles. We're not in a position to ditch redux-form at the moment since our architecture relies on it quite heavily, but will be exploring these ideas further...

Comment: I didn't say you should ditch redux-form at all. But you really should not use it _everywhere_. There are cases where redux-form is unnecessary, including the above case, imho.